# query a telephone number mysql lots of formats

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a search where the last 5 digits of a number match out of 12

For example
text column "tel" contains "44 20 01122 4455" There maybe spaces there may not be spaces. It may not have a country code at the front, it may have a "0" and it could be a variable length from 13 digits to just 4 digits.

I would like to be able to match the following numbers and return the record.
44 20 01122 4455 (last 13 digits with spaces)
4420011224455 (last 13 digits no spaces)
020 01122 4455 (last 10 digits with spaces)
020011224455 (last 10 digits no spaces)
011224455 (last 9 digits)
224455 (last 6 digits)
24455 (last 5 digits)
4455 (last 4 digits)

The most common problem I will need to find is numbers stored as:
44 20 01122 4455 (last 13 digits with spaces)
4420011224455 (last 13 digits no spaces)
020 01122 4455 (last 10 digits with spaces)
020011224455 (last 10 digits no spaces)

but I only get 4455 or 24455 to search with

What mysql search query commands can I use?

Comment: Are you selling double glazing or offering to claim back PPI payments? If so, then there is no way of doing what you ask. ;)

Comment: Quite the opposite. I'm blocking them

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ' ' FROM RIGHT(LPAD(REPLACE(tel, ' ', ''), 13, ' '), 13))
```

This should replace all spaces with blanks. Then it will pad the string with spaces till its 13 characters long (in case its only 4 characters). Then it will trim the leading spaces it padded.

Comment: This looks good but is there not a function which looks at records and says this is the best match there is but not so bad it will match to anything? I ask because this search assumes the last 4 digits are unique but what if there are two records where the last 4 match? We need to goto 5 or 6 digits. Thanks

Comment: Hmm tested the idea and it doesn't work. If for example I have "12311 2580" stored and I send mysql 2580 I get no results returned. If I send "12311 2580" an exact match I get no results returned but if I store and send "2580" I get a record returned. Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: Search against my `SELECT` statement in my answer. It should absolutely work.

Comment: So I'm doing this SELECT date, tel FROM db.table WHERE TRIM(LEADING ' ' FROM RIGHT(LPAD(REPLACE(tel, ' ', ''), 13, ' '), 13))='${ARG1}'

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
SELECT tel
  FROM yourTable
 WHERE RIGHT( REPLACE ( tel, ' ', ''), 5) = @param
```

The `REPLACE()` function removes any spaces.  The `RIGHT()` function gets the last five characters.